# How to import 2 different certificates with maven

Tags: java, maven, keytool

I need to import two different certificates in my build process. I'm using [keytool-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/keytool/keytool-maven-plugin/), I'm able to import 1 plugin but I'm not able to import 2 different ones.

Here is my pom snippet

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>importCertificate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <keystore>${project.build.directory}/client-truststore.jks</keystore>
        <storepass>storepass</storepass>
        <alias>alias</alias>
        <file>ca.pem</file>
        <noprompt>true</noprompt>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about making two executions ?

Comment: how should I give 2 different configurations to 2 different executions?

Comment: @small_ticket just try putting the configuration tag within the execution once. ;)

Comment: @nullpointer then how should I give the two different certificate file and alias? I may misunderstand it, can you please post an example?

Comment: @small_ticket - okay just to clear, you want both the certificates in the same build process? or would you use them for different build processes?

Comment: @nullpointer poor me! I didn't read the maven error logs well enough. I resolved it. It was about not giving the id for each execution. Please post an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things -

- as discussed and inferred above `<id>` is something that you are missing in your `<execution>` tag
- also, if you want to make the alias configurable please use `changeAlias` in your execution as -

  ```
  <goals>
      <goal>changeAlias</goal>
  </goals>
  ```

Source - [Keytool Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/keytool/keytool-maven-plugin/usage.html)

**How to use `keytool:changeAlias` specifying parameters on the command line**

> ```
> > mvn keytool:changeAlias -Dkeystore=/path/to/your/keystore
> > -Dstorepass=storepass -Dkeypass=keypass -Dalias=foo_alias \  -Ddestalias=new_alias
> ```

- and for different executions you can try to configure different aliases as follows -

  ```
  <executions>
     <execution>
         <goals>
           <goal>importCertificate</goal>
         </goals>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <id>executionOne</id>
         <configuration>
           <keystore>${project.build.directory}/client-truststore.jks</keystore>
           <storepass>storepass</storepass>
           <alias>alias</alias>
           <file>ca.pem</file>
           <noprompt>true</noprompt>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
         <goals>
           <goal>importCertificate</goal>
         </goals>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <id>executionTwo</id>
         <!--change this from one above-->
         <configuration>
           <keystore>${project.build.directory}/client-truststore.jks</keystore>
           <storepass>storepass</storepass>
           <alias>alias</alias>
           <file>ca.pem</file>
           <noprompt>true</noprompt>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
  </executions>
  ```

Comment: I am using this solution but have a problem: It works fine when built the first time or after a clean. But if the keystore already exists from a previous run the build will fail. There is no real way to mitigate, so I filed https://github.com/mojohaus/keytool/issues/15